# I can't seem to open two windows with python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting an error trying to open a window in python
I am using `tkinter` so the code looks a bit like this

```
from tkinter import *
Window = Tk()
Window2 = Tk()
Window.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100) # border
Window2.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

Comment: Please post the actual error, along with code which reproduces the issue you have.

Comment: Module not found? Typo? What is `tikneter`?

Comment: Sorry, bad question I will delete it as soon as possible

Comment: I agree that this question isn't great, but there's no need to delete it. And it's considered bad manners on SO to delete questions that have useful answers.

Comment: Don't delete questions that have been answered, and don't vandalize your post! Deleting your question is very rude to the person who took their time to answer your question, even if your question is stupid. [It can go real bad for you too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/5067311).

Comment: Creating two instances of `Tk()` won't work the way you expect. If you need a second window, create an instance of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some basic typos / syntax errors in your code. But anyway...

A Tkinter window doesn't have `create_rectangle` method. However, the Canvas widget *does* have that method; you can use it like this.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=100, height=100)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(1, 1, 99, 99, outline="blue", fill="white") 
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the question already has an accepted answer. It doesn't actually answer the question on creating another window.

You should always avoid having multiple instances of `Tk()` if you need another window the `Toplevel` widget is what you should look towards.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text = "This is the main window").pack()

sub_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
tk.Label(sub_window, text = "This is the other window").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -4):

You should use: import tkinter

Comment: This doesn't actually fix it. Or do anything. In fact, it breaks the existing code.